# JPA and Immutable value for @Embeddable fields

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a weird, yet perhaps expected, behaviour of JPA with immutable POJOs.
I teach the use of Spring using a simple project as basis. In its first versions, everything is handmade, without magick. Hence, I took the advantage to introduce my students to the benefit of immutable objects.

I created a simple immutable Address class, with an associated builder, and included it as a field in a Customer object.

When I moved to JPA, I felt that @Embedded and @Embeddable were the way to go.

Hence I got

```java
@Embeddable
public final class Address {
    public static final Address EMPTY_ADDRESS = new Address("", "", "", "", "", "");

    private  final String street1;
    private  final String street2;
    private  final String city;
    private  final String state;
    private  final String zipcode;
    private  final String country;

...
}
```

And, as far as JPA goes, my tests went well. But.. notice the EMPTY_ADDRESS constant? Before going to Spring, I had written tests which took advantage of immutability, such as :

```java
@Test
public void testEmptyBuilder() {
  Address a = Address.builder().build();
  assertEquals(Address.EMPTY_ADDRESS, a);
}
```

They work in isolation... But when I run all the tests, if the JPA tests run before the tests for Address, the result is that JPA will write into my poor EMPTY_ADDRESS (which happens to be the initial value for a customer address), instead of creating a new Address object.

I guess it can be expected, but, apart from foregoing the claim to immutability, is there a good way to do this in JPA? And, apart from immutability, what is the expected behaviour of JPA if :

a. we share an embeddable objet (with the same address) between two JPA entities ;
b. we change the value of one of them by calling a setter, like :

```
customer.setAddress(new Address(....));
```

P.S. I know that a very similar question has been asked, but it was ten years ago, and at that time, the code would not even run. In my case, the problem is that my immutable object is mutated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hibernate 6.1 introduces support for real immutable embeddable objects by invoking the appropriate constructor, but since classes can have logic in the constructor you'd have to write a custom `EmbeddableInstantiator` to model this.
Since 6.2 there is out of the box support for Java records as embeddables like this:

```java
@Embeddable
public record Address(
    String street1,
    String street2,
    String city,
    String state,
    String zipcode,
    String country) {

    public static final Address EMPTY_ADDRESS = new Address("", "", "", "", "", "");
...
}
```

Also see https://in.relation.to/2022/12/22/orm-62-cr1/ for reference.